# Is equipotent $\sim$ relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Problem: $\sim$ is the mark for bijection between two set. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be sets. Then$$A \sim A\\A\sim B \Rightarrow B\sim A\\(A\sim B \land B\sim C )\Rightarrow A\sim C$$
I know that is not a relation because it is define on set that contains all set which is not set. But my professor told that if I write like this it is OK.

Let $A,B,C\subset U$ where $U$ is some universal set. Then$$A \sim A\\A\sim B \Rightarrow B\sim A\\(A\sim B \land B\sim C )\Rightarrow A\sim C$$
Because I define relation $\sim$ on $P(U) × P(U)$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: It is a **relation on** $\wp(U)$ or equivalently a **subset of** $\wp(U)\times\wp(U)$.